# How to add layout for subview and subview button label step by step in ios?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

How to add constraint for subview of view controller 
 explain briefly

Comment: please elaborate your question a little

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a new view
self.containerView = [UIView new];
// before adding constraints always add respective view to superview
[self.view addSubview:self.containerView]; 
[self.containerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];

// add container on newly added view
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraintContainer = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraintContainer = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.containerView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *trailingConstraintContainer = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.containerView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraintContainer = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

// add constraint to superview of respective view
[self.view addConstraints:@[topConstraintContainer,leadingConstraintContainer,trailingConstraintContainer,bottomConstraintContainer]];
```

There are alot of possibilities, but this is the main flow
Also there are third party libraries available which makes adding constraints easier, like
[PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)